# Combining j.truncate on a div with animate marginLeft on div P tags jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, truncate

Am trying to use animate marginLeft on text within a div, which is itself being animated by j.truncate, but it doesn't seem to be working.

J truncate is working fine for me and so is my animate margin left, but combined, they dont work yet.

Any answers out there?

Here's j.truncate by itself http://jsfiddle.net/cress/QLgqe/19/ (have used different text)

Here's the animate by itself http://jsfiddle.net/cress/pZ6aL/2/

Here's the combo of j.truncate and animate http://jsfiddle.net/cress/mGnvu/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem was some minor syntax errors, which I fixed for you in the fiddle below.

The second was that your DOM had been changed -- the jTruncate plugin modifies the DIV it acts on so that the selector `$('#works > p')` no longer worked. Changing it to `$('#works p')` would fix things, but might not always be specific enough; changing it to `$('#works span.truncate_more > p')` solved everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mGnvu/12/

Comment: Yes, I saw the expected '}' at line 124, but not sure what to do!

Comment: Thankyou so much! I didn't know that this plugin would do that, quite the irritation. Coding can be quite complex. I should learn more about how span.truncate_more works.

Comment: Using Firebug for Firefox or the built-in debugging tools that come with IE, Chrome or Safari could help you with cases like this. By inspecting the DOM elements, you can look at what the browser sees and deduce problem like this in the future.